# Generate dataframe columns based on constraints in current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with the following columns :

```
Date_2      Date_1     is_B
02/08/2019  01/09/2019  1
02/08/2019  01/09/2019  1
02/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
02/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  0
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  1
31/08/2019  01/09/2019  1
```

I want to generate another dataframe df2 such that the output looks like the following :

```
Date_1  Total_count Total(is_b = 1) num_2   num_3   num_5   num_20
01/09/2019  493      147            26      30      32       59

Total_Count = total entries for Date_1 in the dataframe 
Total(is_b = 1) = total entries for Date_1 where is_b = 1
num_2 = total entries for Date_1 for 2 days where Date_2 = (Date_1 - 1 to Date_1 - 2){Both included as well}
num_3 = total entries for Date_1 for 3 days where Date_2 = (Date_1 - 3 to Date_1 - 5){Both included as well}
num_5 = total entries for Date_1 for 5 days where Date_2 = (Date_1 - 6 to Date_1 - 10){Both included as well}
num_20 = total entries for Date_1 for 20 days where Date_2 = (Date_1 - 11 to Date_1 - 30){Both included as well}
```

I was able to generate first 2 columns easily using :

```
df.groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count()

df.loc[df.isBooked == 1].groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count()
```

I am not sure how to calculate the other columns :

I did try this :

```
df.loc[(df.isBooked == 1) & (df.Booking_Date = Flight_Date - 1) & (df.Booking_Date = Flight_Date - 2)].groupby('Flight_Date')['Flight_Date'].count().reset_index(name='num_2')
```

But this is an invalid syntax altogether.

Can anyone help me with generating the columns num_2, num_3, num_5, num_20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has two parts.

#### Date parsing

It appears from the example, that date is *not* parsed - they are strings.
They must be parsed to perform date operations.

```py
import pandas as pd

def dateparse(d):
    return pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')

for c in ['Date_1', 'Date_2']:
    df[c] = df[c].map(dateparse)
```

If you print `df`, it should look like this (notice date format):

```
       Date_2     Date_1  is_B
0  2019-08-02 2019-09-01     1
1  2019-08-02 2019-09-01     1
2  2019-08-02 2019-09-01     0
3  2019-08-02 2019-09-01     0
```

Now, the columns have `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

#### Calculation of statistics

We will calculate a few series with `Date_1` as index, and then merge them.

```py
total_count = df.groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count().rename('Total_Count')

total_count_is_b = df[df.is_B == 1].groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'] \
    .count().rename('Total(is_b = 1)')
```

To get `num_2` perform this:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

num_2_df = df[
    (df.is_B == 1) &
    df.Date_2.between(
        df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=2),
        df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=1)
    )
].groupby('Date_1')['Date_2'].count().rename('num_2')

# notice argument order of `pandas.Series.between`
```

Other `num_3`, `num_5`, `num_20` can be calculated analogously:

```py
num_3_df = df[
  (df.is_B == 1) &
  df.Date_2.between(df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=5), df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=3))
].groupby('Date_1')['Date_2'].count().rename('num_3')

num_5_df = df[
  (df.is_B == 1) &
  df.Date_2.between(df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=10), df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=6))
].groupby('Date_1')['Date_2'].count().rename('num_5')

num_20_df = df[
  (df.is_B == 1) &
  df.Date_2.between(df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=30), df.Date_1 - timedelta(days=11))
].groupby('Date_1')['Date_2'].count().rename('num_20')
```

Finally all columns are merged to one table:

```py
result_df = pd.concat(
    [total_count, total_count_is_b, num_2_df, num_3_df, num_5_df, num_20_df],
    axis=1
).fillna(0).astype(int)

result_df = result_df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However, like I mentioned in the question, the num_2 or num_3 in the dataframe for each unique date_1.

The output would look like this : 

Date_1 Total_Count Total(is_b = 1) num_2   num_3   num_5   num_20

Comment: Edited answer to get dataframe on output.

Comment: Slapek This really helps and now easy to understand as well.